# Null-spaces modulo n

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, knot-theory

Let A and B be square integer-valued matrices (possibly of different size) such that their null-spaces modulo n (i.e. the set of vectors v that satisfy Av = 0 mod n) are isomorphic (i.e. there exists a bijection f with f(0)=0 and f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)) for all n. Moreover, there exist functions F and G that work as isomorphisms for all n (with F∘G=id on the null-spaces). Can we show that the determinants of A&B are equal up to a sign?

For context, this is from knot theory. I am trying to prove that the determinants of the Goeritz and the colouring matrix are equal up to a sign, and so far I've got this.

Comment: In your definition of isomorphic, is the bijection meant to be a bijection between sets of integer-valued matrices?

Comment: It's between sets that I called null-spaces mod n.

Comment: Do the vectors in those sets necessarily have integer entries?

Comment: Yes, everything here is in Z (or Z/nZ when talking mod n). Also, I'm pretty sure that if F and G were expressed as matrices, they would also have integer entries.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.08044) gives a citation for a proof of the result that you're looking for: W. B. R. Lickorish. An Introduction to Knot Theory. Springer GTM , 1997. It also provides its own proof of the paper (see Theorem 14 and Exercise 15).

Comment: Thanks! That's actually a paper I've seen before; e problem is exactly in exercise 15 where it connects the previous bit with the determinants. It starts with "n divides det C <=> C has a nontrivial solution in Z/nZ", but this implication actually only works one way (=>). In order to get a nontrivial solution mod n, it's enough to have gcd(n, det C)>1, so n doesn't have to divide det C. So now I'm trying to fill in this gap.

Comment: Don't $A=[2]$ and $B=2\cdot I_2$ constitute a counter-example?

Comment: @BenGrossmann actually, OP has stated that they can have different sizes.

Comment: A and B don't have to be of the same size, but your example doesn't actually give isomorphic null-spaces? Take even n=2, the first matrix has Z/2Z as its null space, and the second one has (Z/2Z)^2

Comment: An observation you might find helpful: the null space of $A$ modulo $n$ is isomoprhic (as an abelian group) to
$$
(\Bbb Z / \gcd (\alpha_1,n) \Bbb Z) \times  \cdots \times (\Bbb Z/ \gcd (\alpha_k,n) \Bbb Z),
$$
where $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ denote the [invariant factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of $A$. The determinant of $A$ is (up to a sign) the product of these invariant factors.

Comment: Interesting, this actually looks pretty similar to the colouring group. And actually, doesn't this mean that if n=det B we get that det A = 0 mod n? But then by symmetry det A and det B are multiples of each other and are therefore equal. (Also, this would mean that they have the same invariant factors, which would prove another result involving the colouring group). What is the name of the theorem you're referring to?

Comment: @MaxBow-Arrow I don't know of any name for this, but it can be quickly proved using the existence of [the Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). If you like, I could post the proof of this result as an answer.

Comment: That'd be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> **Claim:** The null space of the size $k$ square matrix $A$ modulo $n$ is isomoprhic (as an abelian group) to
> $$
> (\Bbb Z / \gcd (\alpha_1,n) \Bbb Z) \times  \cdots \times (\Bbb Z/ \gcd (\alpha_k,n) \Bbb Z),
> $$
> where $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ are the [invariant factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of $A$.

*Proof:* Let $D$ denote the Smith normal form of $A$, and let $U,V$ be unimodular  matrices (integer matrices with integer matrix inverses) such that $A = UDV$. Note that the null space of $A$ is equal to the nullspace of $U^{-1}A = DV$. Furthermore, the map $\phi(x) = Vx$ defines an isomorphism over $(\Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z)^k$ that restricts to a bijection from the nullspace of $DV$ to the nullspace of $D$.  Thus, it suffices to determine the nullspace of $D$ up to isomorphism.

For $x = (x_1,\dots,x_k) \in (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^k$, we compute
$$
Dx = (\alpha_1 x_1,\dots,\alpha_kx_k).
$$
We see that $x \in \operatorname{null}(D) \iff n \mid \alpha_i x_i$ for $i = 1,\dots, k$. Equivalently, the null space consists of the vectors $x$ for which $(n/\gcd(\alpha_i,n)) \mid x_i$ for each $i = 1,\dots,k$.

From there, note that the multiples of $n/\gcd(\alpha_i,n)$ modulo $n$ form a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/\gcd(\alpha_i,n) \Bbb Z$.

Comment: See my latest edit. We can neatly circumvent this issue by considering only the prime integers $n$.

Comment: "$\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ have the same prime divisors, which means they are indeed the same up to a sign." What about, say, $p$ and $p^2$?